# Enter key in textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a `textarea`, On every <kbd>Enter</kbd> key pressed in `textarea` I want new line to be started with a bullet say (*). How to go about it ?

No jQuery please.

I can observe for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key , after that !? Should I have to get the whole value of `textarea` and append * to it and again fill the `textarea` ?

Comment: Following the hint below , I got to the solution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<body>

<textarea id="txtArea" onkeypress="onTestChange();"></textarea>

<script>
function onTestChange() {
    var key = window.event.keyCode;

    // If the user has pressed enter
    if (key === 13) {
        document.getElementById("txtArea").value = document.getElementById("txtArea").value + "\n*";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
```

Although the new line character feed from pressing enter will still be there, but its a start to getting what you want.

Comment: This will only work in IE: `window.event` is not supported in other browsers.

Comment: Doug Crockford told me to tell you to use === instead of ==.

Comment: if you write onkeypress="return onTestChange();" then original new line character will be left out.

Comment: Not very useful if you hit Enter and one or more lines already exists after the line. It will end up deleting all the lines after the new line.

Comment: To use in modern browsers, replace `onkeypress="onTestChange();"` with `onkeypress="onTestChange(event);"` and replace `function onTestChange() {` with `function onTestChange(e) {` and replace `var key = window.event.keyCode;` with `var key = e.keyCode`

Answer (score 17):

Simply add this tad to your textarea.

```
onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) return false;"
```

Comment: Maybe you can expand upon this answer. It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8):

You need to consider the case where the user presses enter in the middle of the text, not just at the end. I'd suggest detecting the enter key in the `keyup` event, as suggested, and use a regular expression to ensure the value is as you require:

```
<textarea id="t" rows="4" cols="80"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatTextArea(textArea) {
        textArea.value = textArea.value.replace(/(^|\r\n|\n)([^*]|$)/g, "$1*$2");
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var textArea = document.getElementById("t");
        textArea.onkeyup = function(evt) {
            evt = evt || window.event;

            if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                formatTextArea(this);
            }
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: `evt = evt || window.event;` : What is this line for ?

Comment: @Fifi: That's for old versions of Internet Explorer (8 and under, I think) that didn't pass the event as a parameter to the event hanbdler, instead using the global `window.event`. It's not necessary now.

Answer (score 3):

My scenario is when the user strikes the enter key while typing in textarea i have to include a line break.I achieved this using the below code......Hope it may helps somebody......

```
function CheckLength()
{
    var keyCode = event.keyCode
    if (keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_id_txt_Suggestions').value = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_id_txt_Suggestions').value + "\n<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
$("#txtArea").on("keypress",function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;

    // If the user has pressed enter
    if (key == 13) {
        document.getElementById("txtArea").value =document.getElementById("txtArea").value + "\n";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="txtArea"></textarea>
```

Comment: No jQuery he said