# Detection for auto indentation in TextArea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea where users can input text.

If the current line starts with 3 spaces and the user hits enter, it will automatically insert 3 spaces and set the cursor right after the spaces. (there may be text before or after)

How can I detect such pattern with JavaScript?

Comment: [start here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript). please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea) explains how to figure out where the caret is when the user hits enter so that you can check whether there are three spaces and a line break to the left.

[Enter key in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099661/enter-key-in-textarea) explains how to detect the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in a textarea and take an action.

Once you have a listener hooked up and know the caret location is `caret`, you can do something like

```
if (/(?:^|[\r\n])   (?:[^\r\n ][^\r\n]*)?$/
    .test(myTextArea.value.substring(0, caret)) {
  ...
}
```

to take an action when there are exactly three spaces at the start of the current line.

To insert the 3 extra-spaces, you could do something like

```
myTextArea.value = myTextArea.value.substring(0, caret)
    + "\n    " + myTextArea.value.substring(caret);
```