# how to add "•" each time i hit enter key in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add "•" each time I hit enter key in my textarea. I've been searching the codes of it. But I can't seem to find it. or after hitting the enter key and if I inputted a word, that's the only time it will add "•" before the word. Help please.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: add it where? the beginning of the current line? end of the current line? start of the next line? above or below the textarea?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that this is a bulleted list, not a multi-line password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enter key in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099661/enter-key-in-textarea)

Comment: Don't do this while the user is filling out the textarea. That's way more work than it's worth. Altering the value of the textarea while it is focused means having to get and reset the cursor position when you alter it. It's easy to make this replacement later by splitting the text on `\n`

Comment: thanks for the comment guys. i found the answer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/uPALIRU/1/

```
$('textarea').on('keydown',function(e){
  var t = $(this);
  switch(e.which){
  case 13:
    t.val(t.val()+'•');
    return false;
  }  
});
```

Comment: but how about, on the time that hit a character on a keyboard. it will automatically add the bullet?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something along the lines of this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#List').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) { // If enter is pressed.
      var content = this.value;
      var sel = getInputSelection(this);
      var caret = getCaret(this);
      var bullet = "• ";
      this.value = content.substring(0,caret) +
                   bullet +
                   content.substring(caret,content.length);
      setInputSelection(
        this,
        sel.start + bullet.length,
        sel.end + bullet.length
      );
      event.stopPropagation();  
    }
  });
});
```

with the `getCaret()` function stolen from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702/how-do-i-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea) and the `getInputSelection()` and `setInputSelection()` functions stolen from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3288215/1103543).

Full (somewhat messy) JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xjKDG/12/).

This has the advantage of behaving more like a text editor. If your cursor is not at the end of the textarea and you press enter, you want the bullet to appear at your cursor, not just get added to the end of the textarea.

**Edit:**

Added cursor position resetting.

Comment: Hey Jacob, in your JSFiddle example, do you know how to avoid the cursor goes always to the end of the textarea when you press enter? thanks!

Comment: Great question. It looks like that behavior is the default for when you update a textarea's `value`, based on some quick searching which led me to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286595/update-textarea-value-but-keep-cursor-position). I've incorporated one of the answers there into my code.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you wish to make a bulleted list, prefixing lines with a bullt (•)

```
  var linestart = function(txt, st) {
    var ls = txt.split("\n");
    var i = ls.length-1;
    ls[i] = st+ls[i];
    return ls.join("\n");
  };
  $('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var t = $(this);
    if(e.which == 13) {
      t.val(linestart(t.val(), '•') + "\n");
      return false;
    }  
  });
```